# how I can show multiples datatables with only one datasource angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

how i can show  n numbers of mattables with diferent data by service if i have currently only one table with one datasource

```
  columns = [
    { columnDef: 'position', header: 'No.',    cell: (element: any) => `${element.position}` },
    { columnDef: 'name',     header: 'Name',   cell: (element: any) => `${element.name}`     },
    { columnDef: 'weight',   header: 'Weight', cell: (element: any) => `${element.weight}`   },
    { columnDef: 'symbol',   header: 'Symbol', cell: (element: any) => `${element.symbol}`   },
  ];

  displayedColumns = this.columns.map(c => c.columnDef);
  dataSource = new ExampleDataSource();
 
}


const ELEMENT_DATA: any[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
  {position: 11, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na'},
  {position: 12, name: 'Magnesium', weight: 24.305, symbol: 'Mg'},
  {position: 13, name: 'Aluminum', weight: 26.9815, symbol: 'Al'},
  {position: 14, name: 'Silicon', weight: 28.0855, symbol: 'Si'},
  {position: 15, name: 'Phosphorus', weight: 30.9738, symbol: 'P'},
  {position: 16, name: 'Sulfur', weight: 32.065, symbol: 'S'},
  {position: 17, name: 'Chlorine', weight: 35.453, symbol: 'Cl'},
  {position: 18, name: 'Argon', weight: 39.948, symbol: 'Ar'},
  {position: 19, name: 'Potassium', weight: 39.0983, symbol: 'K'},
  {position: 20, name: 'Calcium', weight: 40.078, symbol: 'Ca'},
];


export class ExampleDataSource extends DataSource<any> {

  connect(): Observable<Element[]> {
    return Observable.of(ELEMENT_DATA);  
  }

  disconnect() {}
}
```

in my html component I show the table and the datasource like this

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" [cdkColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
      <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>{{ column.header }}</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{ column.cell(row) }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

for example I want to filter by weight and show all those that have the same weight in a table

my expected result

[image]

Comment: May I suggest you provide a StackBlitz demo of your current code?

Comment: you can use group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your filter params are fixed ,for instance if it's **weight**, i have tried to edit basic example of `mat-table` from [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-basic)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSources:Record<number, PeriodicElement[]>;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSources = ELEMENT_DATA.reduce((grouped, current) => {
      grouped[current.weight] = grouped[current.weight] || [];
      grouped[current.weight].push(current);
      return grouped;
    }, {} as Record<number, PeriodicElement[]>);
  }
}
```

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let dataSource of dataSources | keyvalue">
  <div>Weight: {{dataSource.key}}</div>

  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource.value" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
</ng-container>
```

If you have to filter by any other params, create a separate function/s which will try to group the data based on that param.

Also you can change the `Weight:`  in template to something dynamic if it's required.

Answer (score 0):

You should use angular component which is really good and tested ,

> UI-Grid 4.0 (formerly ng-grid), is a 100% angular grid written with no
> dependencies other than AngularJS. It is designed around a core grid
> module and features are layered on as angular modules and directives.
> This keeps the core small and focused while executing very complex
> features only when you need them.
>
> In the core module, you get:
>
> Virtualized rows and columns - only the rows and columns visible in
> the viewport (+ some extra margin) are actually rendered Bind cells to
> complex properties and functions Column sorting with three states:
> Asc, Desc, None Column filtering Ability to change header and cell
> contents with custom templates i18nService allows label translations

- http://ui-grid.info/